# List Indices must be integer or slices, not float

Tags: python, list, function, calculator, median

So I was creating a median calculator, and I came upon this error (the heading)

```
    def median(x):
      #finds the median of a column
      if len(x) % 2 == 0:
        y = len(x) / 2
        medknot = x[y] + x[y][-1]
        med = medknot / 2
        return med
      elif len(x) % 2 == 1:
        y = len(x)//2
        med = x[y]
        return med

    l1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 5]
    print(median(l1))
```

What is the error in my code?

Comment: The error message seems completely clear. Which line of code causes the exception? Are you indexing with a float on that line?

Comment: `y = len(x) / 2` gives you a float

Comment: y = len(x) / 2 >> y = len(x) // 2

Comment: x[y] is takinf a float number in y. So you need an integer to find the position in your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` always returns a float, even if the result could be an integer.

```
>>> 1/1
1.0
```

Use:

```
y = len(x) // 2
```

Also, the next line doesn't make sense:

```
medknot = x[y] + x[y][-1]
```

As the output of `x[y]` should be a scalar. You probably want `medknot = x[y] + x[y-1]`

Finally, the input list should be sorted to compute a correct median.

You can also simplify the code:

```
def median(x):
    # sort x
    x = sorted(x)

    y = len(x) // 2 
    med = x[y]
    if len(x) % 2 == 0:
        med = (med + x[y-1])/2
    return med

print(median([1, 2, 3]))
# 2

print(median([1, 2, 3, 4]))
# 2.5

print(median([4, 1, 2, 3]))
# 2.5
```